# Android EditText input and virtual keyboard handling

Tags: android, input, keyboard, android-edittext

Is it possible in some way to retrieve the input of an EditText without needing to add a dedicated button underneath (e.g. "SET"), just by touching the "Done" button on the emerging keyboard (Android 2.3.1)?

And if yes, can I somehow handle this event for proceeding to further actions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
            // do your stuff here
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

As for the second part what do you mean by *somehow handle this event for proceeding to further actions?*

Comment: Thank you very much! You covered the second part also by "//do your stuff here" :)